# calling a WS-Secured SOAP webservice from Groovy

Tags: web-services, soap, groovy, webservice-client

How do I call a WS-Secured SOAP web service implementing [oasis standard](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0.pdf)

I am not sure whether HTTPbuilder can be used to access SOAP based web services. The popular groovy [WSlite library](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite) can be used to access SOAP web services using basic authentication only.

Is there any groovy library or sample which could be used to access WS-security user name token implemented SOAP web service from groovy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WS lite can be used to acess ws-secure web service. We have to build the security header and can generate nonce, password digest, time stamp and have then sent in the WSe security header.